# Shell Script Parameters in String

Tags: linux, string, shell

I have a shell script that I pass some parameters to. In this script I'm building a simple json string.

Here's the shell script A:

```
firstname=${1}
lastname={$2}
email={$3}

json='{"firstname":"'"$firstname"'","lastname":"'"$lastname"'","email":"'"$email"'"}'

# do web request here
```

This gets called by shell script B like this:

```
firstname="aa"
lastname="bb"
email="cc@cc.cc"
./scriptB.sh ${firstname} ${lastname} ${email}
```

After I post this json to a server all the values in the json arrive encapsulated in curly braces: {aa}, {bb}, {cc@cc.cc}. The server cannot be the problem in this case.

I think this has something to do with improper escaping or wrong usage of string quotes?

Comment: All of them are enclosed in curly braces?  If your sample code is accurate, firstname should not have the braces, but lastname and email will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first script `{` and `}` are inconsistent and unquoted. Try:

```
firstname="${1}"
lastname="${2}"
email="${3}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that when I'm back home and let you know if this worked.

Comment: It worked like this:

firstname="${1}"
lastname="${2}"
email="${3}"